# joining strings with a delimiter between them in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to combine two strings with a delimiter between them using `strncat` but i'm not able to get the exact results .Please let me know why is it getting wrong .

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main()
  { 
     char Buff[100];
     memset(Buff,0,sizeof(Buff));
     char *Ip="192.168.4.10";
     char *Ip2="192.168.4.20";
     strcpy(Buff,Ip);

     strncat(Buff,"||",sizeof("||"));

     strncat(Buff,Ip2,sizeof(Ip2));
     printf("%s",Buff);


  }
```

I'm getting the output as `192.168.4.10||192.` instead of the concatenation of the two data.What could have gone wrong . Is there still more efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `strncat(Buff,Ip2, sizeof(Ip2));` is wrong because `sizeof(Ip2)`  gives size of `Ip2` pointer but not length of string pointed by `Ip2`.

In your system size of char pointer is 4 bytes that is why strncat() could append only 4 chars from string `Ip2` (`1`, `9`, `2`, `.`).

You are confuse between `sizeof()` operator and length of string. Note  `sizeof("||")` gives you `3` ( that is number of bytes `"||"` takes) while it's length is `2`.

Additionally, the first `strncat(Buff,"||",sizeof("||"));` working well because third char is `\0`.

To rectify your code use `strlen(char *)` function from `string.h` header file:

```
strncat(Buff, "||", strlen("||"));
strncat(Buff, Ip2, strlen(Ip2));
```

[Check this working code](http://codepad.org/C8keI2h6)

Comment: sorry should have been strlen instead of that . My mistake .Didn't notice.

Comment: @blitz use `strlen()` function from `string.h` library

Comment: yeah did that and solved the problem . typed sizeof by mistake :)